# org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The class file is not on the classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

from the beginning, while trying to deploy a war under Jetty, I have an error, and in order to understand from where the error is comming, I would like to put a breakpoint in a class (SimpleCDI) located in a dependency (a jar which is downloaded by MAVEN). I work under MAC and when I hit Command + Shift + T and look up "SimpleCDI" class, it points that the class is within org.jboss.weld package

Here is a printscreen of my research
[image]

And when I click on the "C SimpleCDI org.jboss.weld" line, it returns an error message

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The class file is not on the classpath
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ClassFileEditor.doSetInput(ClassFileEditor.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$5.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3154)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$14.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2195)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2191)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3172)
```

I checked that I have the right dependency (weld-servlet-2.4.5.Final.jar) with
SimpleCDI" in it.

I noticed that the eclipse icon of my dependency "weld-servlet-2.4.5.Final.jar" is the following
[image]

It is a jar file without attached source. Actually, I can see this dependency in Eclipse in one of my module "Tourism-Services" (I have a Maven multi module project) in the "Referenced Librairies" folder with the icon mentioned above, but the Maven dependency that import this jar is located in another module "Tourism-Core" which is imported itself in "Tourism-Services" module. I notice in passing that I cannot see "weld-servlet-2.4.5.Final.jar" in "Referenced Librairies" folder of "Tourism-Core" module (why ?)

My main question is : why cannot I edit "SimpleCDI" class and put a breakpoint in order to debug upstream

Answer (score 1):

I've also been using the CodeMix plugin, have you tried to remove the Open Type binding from the CodeMix preferences? Preferences -> Codemix -> Bindings. From there uncheck the "Open Types on COMMAND+SHIFT+T" and do apply and close. This will get you to use the regular Open Java Type from Eclipse.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes it is a solution

Answer (score 0):

a plugin was causing the error. It is CodeMix plugin

I tried to uninstall it : help->Eclipse Marketplace->Installed
I obtain the following screen

[image]

I chose uninstall in the dropDown

But it doesn't work.

I have found a workaround : https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/uninstall-codemix/

But it is temporary. I tried to find CodeMix in Eclipse plugin folder (I work under MAC), but there is nothing. Do you see another way  ?